# How i can convert byte array into HttpPostedFileBase image file in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to convert byte array into HttpPostedFileBase file in c# for Web API's. But after conversion, I can not find the file name.

```
public class MemoryPostedFile : HttpPostedFileBase
{
    private readonly byte[] fileBytes;

    public MemoryPostedFile(byte[] fileBytes, string fileName = null)
    {
        this.fileBytes = fileBytes;
        this.FileName = fileName;
        this.InputStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
    }

    public override int ContentLength => fileBytes.Length;

    public override string FileName { get; }

    public override Stream InputStream { get; }
}

HttpPostedFileBase objFile = (HttpPostedFileBase)new MemoryPostedFile(model.UserImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

One observation on your code is that you're not passing in a file name to your `MemoryPostedFile` constructor. Try changing your `objFile` to something like the following:

```
HttpPostedFileBase objFile = (HttpPostedFileBase)new MemoryPostedFile(model.UserImage, model.FileName);
```

Comment: Hi, model.UserImage contains byte array, i am going to convert byte into HttpPostedFileBase image file.

Comment: Do you want to save the byte array as an image file?

Comment: I'm building web api, from mobile side, i get the byte array, so there is the need to convert this byte array into file image again, so i use the above code, the code converts, but i did not found file name.

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me , create this method and pass the value

```
public HttpPostedFile ConstructHttpPostedFile(byte[] data, string filename, string contentType) {
      // Get the System.Web assembly reference
      Assembly systemWebAssembly = typeof (HttpPostedFileBase).Assembly;
      // Get the types of the two internal types we need
      Type typeHttpRawUploadedContent = `enter code here`systemWebAssembly.GetType("System.Web.HttpRawUploadedContent");
      Type typeHttpInputStream = systemWebAssembly.GetType("System.Web.HttpInputStream");
    
      // Prepare the signatures of the constructors we want.
      Type[] uploadedParams = { typeof(int), typeof(int) };
      Type[] streamParams = {typeHttpRawUploadedContent, typeof (int), typeof (int)};
      Type[] parameters = { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeHttpInputStream };
    
      // Create an HttpRawUploadedContent instance
      object uploadedContent = typeHttpRawUploadedContent
        .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, uploadedParams, null)
        .Invoke(new object[]{data.Length, data.Length});
    
      // Call the AddBytes method
      typeHttpRawUploadedContent
        .GetMethod("AddBytes", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Invoke(uploadedContent, new object[] {data, 0, data.Length});
    
      // This is necessary if you will be using the returned content (ie to Save)
      typeHttpRawUploadedContent
        .GetMethod("DoneAddingBytes", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Invoke(uploadedContent, null);
    
      // Create an HttpInputStream instance
      object stream = (Stream)typeHttpInputStream
        .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, streamParams, null)
        .Invoke(new object[] {uploadedContent, 0, data.Length});
    
      // Create an HttpPostedFile instance
      HttpPostedFile postedFile = (HttpPostedFile)typeof(HttpPostedFile)
        .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, parameters, null)
        .Invoke(new object[] {filename, contentType, stream});
    
      return postedFile;
    }
```